# Integração entre bancos Mysql dando erro 1442?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Olá! Eu tenho o seguinte problema a resolver: o banco 1 nao pode interagir diretamente com o banco 3, portanto preciso de uma interface que interaja entre eles, que chamei de banco 2.
O banco 1 insere no banco 2;
o banco 2 insere no banco 3;
o banco 3 insere no banco 2;
o banco 2 insere no banco 3. Espero que tenha ficado claro.
Quando faço a integração entre dois bancos (inserindo do banco 1 no banco 2, ou do banco 3 no banco 2) funciona perfeitamente, mas quando faço a integração com os 3 bancos, me dá o erro 1442:

```
15:27:13    INSERT INTO banco1.Clientes VALUES (42,'mariana', '1998-05-08', '48381856' '4539-6', 'ananana', 'oqe?', '162', 'sasnaush', 'qsjqijqiwj',          'SP', '13720000') Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'clientes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.  0.000 sec
```

Alguem pode me dizer por que esse erro aparece somente quando integro três bancos?

Segue as duas triggers (insert e update):

INSERT

```
DROP TRIGGER insereBanco1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insereBanco1 AFTER INSERT
ON banco1.clientes FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    /* insercao */
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO banco2.Clientes (id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep)
            SELECT id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep FROM banco1.Clientes WHERE
            id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM banco2.Clientes);
    END;
END;
```

UPDATE

```
DROP TRIGGER alteraBanco1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER alteraBanco1 AFTER UPDATE
ON banco1.clientes FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
     /* alteracao */
    BEGIN
        UPDATE banco1.Clientes, banco2.Clientes SET banco2.Clientes.nome = banco1.Clientes.nome, 
        banco2.Clientes.dat_nascimento = banco1.Clientes.dat_nascimento, banco2.Clientes.cpf = banco1.Clientes.cpf,
        banco2.Clientes.rg = banco1.Clientes.rg, banco2.Clientes.endereco = banco1.Clientes.endereco, banco2.Clientes.numero = banco1.Clientes.numero, 
        banco2.Clientes.bairro = banco1.Clientes.bairro, banco2.Clientes.cidade = banco1.Clientes.cidade, banco2.Clientes.estado = banco1.Clientes.estado, banco2.Clientes.cep = banco1.Clientes.cep 
        WHERE banco1.Clientes.id = banco2.Clientes.id;
    END;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Me recomendaram a usar OLD e NEW, mas nao aprendi a usa-las ainda

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode alterar uma tabela enquanto o `Trigger` `INSERT` está disparando. O `INSERT` pode fazer algum bloqueio que pode resultar em um conflito. Além disso, a atualização da tabela a partir de um gatilho faria o mesmo disparar novamente em um loop recursivo infinito. Ambas as razões são por que o `MySQL` impede você de fazer isso.

No entanto, dependendo do que você está tentando alcançar, é possível acessar os novos valores usando NEW.fieldname ou mesmo os valores antigos - se estiver fazendo um UPDATE - com OLD.

Se você tivesse uma linha nomeada `full_brand_namee` desejasse usar as duas primeiras letras como um nome abreviado no campo, `small_namepoderia` usar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `capital` BEFORE INSERT ON `brandnames`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.short_name = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(NEW.full_name,1)) , LCASE(SUBSTRING(NEW.full_name,2)))
END
```

> Resposta traduzida deste post:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already